# Multitexturing not working in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, multitexturing

I followed [this](http://www.clockworkcoders.com/oglsl/tutorial8.htm) tutorial in order to try and achieve multitexturing in LWJGL. But whenever I run my code, the second texture does not show up, or the first texture takes its place. Here is how I bind the textures:

```
ARBMultitexture.glActiveTextureARB(ARBMultitexture.GL_TEXTURE0_ARB);
bindTexture(myTex);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvf (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, EXTTextureEnvCombine.GL_COMBINE_EXT);
glTexEnvf (GL_TEXTURE_ENV,EXTTextureEnvCombine.GL_COMBINE_RGB_EXT, GL_REPLACE);
ARBMultitexture.glActiveTextureARB(ARBMultitexture.GL_TEXTURE1_ARB);
bindTexture(myTex2);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvf (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, EXTTextureEnvCombine.GL_COMBINE_EXT);
glTexEnvf (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, EXTTextureEnvCombine.GL_COMBINE_RGB_EXT, GL_INCR);

drawStuff();
```

myTex and myTex2 both `Textures`, `drawStuff()` is my function where I draw everything.
I use slick for loading the textures and such, here is my bindTexture function:

```
void bindTexture(Texture t) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t.getTextureID());
}
```

In `drawStuff()` I have a custom "Face" class, and here is where I draw everything in there:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glNormal3f(getNormal().x, getNormal().y, getNormal().z);
    glNormal3f(norm1.x, norm1.y, norm1.z);
    ARBMultitexture.glMultiTexCoord2fARB(ARBMultitexture.GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, t1.x, t1.y);
    ARBMultitexture.glMultiTexCoord2fARB(ARBMultitexture.GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, t1.x, t1.y);
    glVertex3f(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z);
    glNormal3f(norm2.x, norm2.y, norm2.z);
    ARBMultitexture.glMultiTexCoord2fARB(ARBMultitexture.GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, t2.x, t2.y);
    ARBMultitexture.glMultiTexCoord2fARB(ARBMultitexture.GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, t2.x, t2.y);
    glVertex3f(p2.x, p2.y, p2.z);
    glNormal3f(norm3.x, norm3.y, norm3.z);
    ARBMultitexture.glMultiTexCoord2fARB(ARBMultitexture.GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, t3.x, t3.y);
    ARBMultitexture.glMultiTexCoord2fARB(ARBMultitexture.GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, t3.x, t3.y);
    glVertex3f(p3.x, p3.y, p3.z);
glEnd();
```

Where `t1, t2, t3, norm1, norm2, norm3, p1, p2, p3` are all instances of a 3D vector class I made (I just keep a 0 in the z component of `t1, t2`, and `t3`). The vertex and fragment shader source is exactly the same as in the aforementioned tutorial.
All the code was working just fine with plain old textures. Any ideas on how I could make this work? Or possibly a better tutorial that is easy to follow when using LWJGL?

Comment: and why wouldn't you consider using shader based approach?

Comment: @MichaelIV I haven't seen anything online about that, I don't know how to do it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to learn from [these tutorials](https://github.com/integeruser/gltut-lwjgl)  how to use modern OpenGL with LWJGL .?If you take a look at the examples in afore mentioned link you will find your ways.I don't know how it works in fixed pipeline but using modern one it's just a matter of plugging several textures into texture targets in fragment shaders and sample those blending texels as you wish.

Comment: Thanks! I should probably stop using fixed pipeline operations in my code :P